# Flutter code coverage reports in VS Code on Windows?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, lcov

Does anyone know a good way to see generated code coverage reports for a Flutter project in Windows, preferably using VS Code? I know I can generate coverage reports using `flutter test --coverage` which generates a coverage file (`coverage\lcov.info`).

But how can I use this in VS Code? I found an extension called *Coverage Gutters* that I can use to visualize covered lines with a green color. It's not perfect for dart/flutter code but it works OK. An example is that it does not mark green lines for line separated arguments to a method or constructor even if those arguments are included in tests.

But the main problem is that I can't get any visual report of the coverage. There are tools (primarily `genhtml`) that are used to generate HTML reports from the lcov.info but this does not seem to be available on Windows. Do I need to install the Linux subsystem for Windows 10 and install genhtml that way?

Please let me know if you have tips on how to use code coverage for Flutter in Windows (reports and/or line visualization in VS Code). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A way--I wouldn't call it a good way, but at least it's easy and it works--is to install [Atom text editor](https://atom.io/) and the Dart and lcov-info packages. Then open your Flutter project and click Ctrl+Alt+c and the coverage report in graphical format will be displayed.